# Parse.com search with wild character using javascript

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I'm trying to create a search function in javascript using parse.com where a field contains a string. I've already search through the documents of parse.com but I can't find something similar to what I want. I want to query something like this:

```
query.like("contents", "%string%"); // example only this code does not exist.
```

Can any one know what method in parse I need?

In iOS I find this method `whereKey:containsString:` but I think `containsString` is not available in javascript.

Comment: Do you mean something like [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf), but with wildcard?

Comment: no I'm referring to parse query.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a way to do this, but the documentation warns that it may timeout on larger data sets. The solution is to add a constraint the query using a regular expression. Use the query constraint [matches(key, regex)](https://parse.com/docs/js/symbols/Parse.Query.html#matches).

Assuming there is a class named "Post" and it has a string attribute named "contents", then:

```
var query = new Parse.Query(Post);
query.matches("contents", ".*string.*");
query.find()
```

To AND multiple conditions, add more query matches constraints:

```
var query = new Parse.Query(Post);
query.matches("contents", ".*string.*");
query.matches("otherAttribute", ".*otherString.*");
query.find()
```

Using the Parse.com JavaScript SDK, it is possible to use a [logical OR](https://www.parse.com/docs/js_guide#queries-compound):

```
var redQuery = new Parse.Query("Post");
redQuery.equalTo("color", "red");

var blueQuery= new Parse.Query("Post");
blueQuery.equalTo("color", "blue");

var mainQuery = Parse.Query.or(redQuery, blueQuery);
```

Comment: what if i want to find matches in 2 column? creating 2 query.matches will return to AND i want to find matches either of the 2 fields. how can i do that?

Comment: It's weird `matches` doesn't appear in their doc's Javascript session, where did you find that?